# Process rows only with Clean data and datatype

Tags: python

I am creating a script that takes in some data and process it row by row. Data types are predefined and if any column value doesn't match with the data type it should store that row in a separate dataframe while all the clean rows are stored in a separate database.

Issue is I can't define the datatypes correctly. For some of the columns I have null values as well which I want the script to discard as dirty row, but the problem is my scripts throws all the values as dirty if it encounters any one column value as null

For example in the given example, I have a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Sample data
data = {
    'Status': [np.nan, 'Pending', 'Rejected'],
    'Event Date': ['2023-07-24', '2023-07-25', '2023-07-26'],
    'Courses': ['Course A', 'Course B', 'Course C'],
    'Country': ['Country 1', 'Country 2', 'Country 3'],
    'Registered': [100, 'canclled', 80],
    'Trained Users (45min)': [np.nan, 40,70]
}

# Create the sample DataFrame
sample_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

In this dataframe the only claan row is at index 2 while the first two rows have issues in them for example. Status and Trained users are null in first row where as Registered is a string in the second row so it should print them as error rows.

My script currently is rejecting all the rows as error rows because I have defined Trained Users as int, if I change the type to Object it returns the row 2 as the only error row.

```
def process_master(Master_trix):
    error_rows = []  # List to store row numbers where errors occurred
    error_rows_print = []
    data_types = {
        'Status': str,
        'Event Date': object,  # Assuming the date is in a valid date format
        'Courses': object,
        'Country': str,
        'Registered': int,
        'Trained Users (45min)': object,
         'Check':object
    }

    try:
        # Check if all required columns are present and have valid data types
        for column, dtype in data_types.items():
        if column not in Master_trix.columns:
            #print(f"Column '{column}' not found. Setting values to NaN.")
            Master_trix[column] =  np.nan
            #print(f"Column '{column}' added")
        invalid_rows = ~Master_trix[column].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, dtype))
        error_rows.extend(Master_trix[invalid_rows].index)
            
        print(error_rows)
        my_errors = set(error_rows)
        # Reset the index of the DataFrame before dropping rows
        Master_trix.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
        if error_rows:
            error_rows_print.append(Master_trix.iloc[error_rows])
        # Remove rows with errors from the DataFrame
        Master_trix.drop(error_rows, inplace=True)
        # Select desired columns
        Master_trix = Master_trix[list(data_types.keys())]

        # Process the data as before...
        # (Note: Commented lines and irrelevant code are omitted for brevity)
        # ...

        # Master_trix['Trained Users (45min)'] = pd.to_numeric(Master_trix['Trained Users (45min)'])
        # Master_trix['Divide'] = Master_trix['Registered'] / Master_trix['Trained Users (45min)']

    except Exception as e:
        log(f'[ERROR] <br/><code>{str(e)}</code>')
        # Handle the error and print the row where the error occurred
        for row_number in error_rows:
            print(f"Error occurred in Row {row_number}:")
            print(Master_trix.iloc[row_number])
        pass

    return Master_trix, error_rows, error_rows_print  # Return the DataFrame and the list of error rows


def main():
    df,error_rows, error_rows_print = process_master(sample_df)
    #print(error_rows_print)
    if len(error_rows) > 0:
        print("Errors occurred in the following rows:")
        for row_number in error_rows:
            print(f"Row {row_number}")
    
    print(error_rows_print)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
        main()
```